# Mysql: Select unique values within the group?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

There are 3 columns - category, material and brand. To be honest it's not a columns from single table but the result of a query from 8 another tables using joins ;)

```
    |   category  |   material   | brand          |
    ----------------------------------------------|
    |  engines    |  product 1   | abb            | -> unique for category "engines"
    |  engines    |  product 2   | wika           | -> unique for category "engines"
    |  engines    |  product 3   | allen-bradley  | -> unique for category "engines"
    |  engines    |  product 5   | wika           |
    |  engines    |  product 6   | e+h            | -> unique for category "engines"
    |  drives     |  product 7   | abb            | -> unique for category "drives"
    |  drives     |  product 8   | wika           | -> unique for category "drives"
    |  drives     |  product 9   | allen-bradley  | -> unique for category "drives"
    |  drives     |  product 10  | e+h            | -> unique for category "drives"
    |  drives     |  product 11  | e+h            |
```

As the result i need smt like this:

```
    |   category  |   material   | brand          | concat(category, brand) |
    ----------------------------------------------|-------------------------|
    |  engines    |  product *   | abb            | engines/abb             |
    |  engines    |  product *   | wika           | engines/wika            |
    |  engines    |  product *   | allen-bradley  | engines/allen-brandley  |
    |  engines    |  product *   | e+h            | engines/e+h             |
    |  drives     |  product *   | abb            | drives/abb              |
    |  drives     |  product *   | wika           | drives/wika             |  
    |  drives     |  product *   | allen-bradley  | drives/allen-bradley    |
    |  drives     |  product *   | e+h            | drives/e+h              |
```

If i use "group by" statement ( GROUP BY CONCAT() ), query time exceeds 10 seconds per 300 results and it doesnt make me happy.

Anyone knows how to get unique values ​​within the group?

UPD:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(url_alias.alias, '/', LOWER(brand_alias.field_brand_path_value)) as real_url 
FROM `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` as th0
LEFT JOIN `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` as th1 ON th0.tid = th1.parent
LEFT JOIN `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` as th2 ON th1.tid = th2.parent
LEFT JOIN `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` as th3 ON th2.tid = th3.parent
LEFT JOIN `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` as th4 ON th3.tid = th4.parent

LEFT JOIN field_data_field_cat_reference as cat_reference ON    
cat_reference.field_cat_reference_tid IN (th0.tid, th1.tid, th2.tid, th3.tid, th4.tid)
LEFT JOIN node n ON cat_reference.entity_id = n.nid
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_brand_reference as brand_reference ON n.nid = brand_reference.entity_id
LEFT JOIN taxonomy_term_data as td_brand ON brand_reference.field_brand_reference_tid = td_brand.tid
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_brand_path as brand_alias ON td_brand.tid = brand_alias.entity_id
LEFT JOIN url_alias ON CONCAT('taxonomy/term/', th0.tid) = url_alias.source
WHERE 1
GROUP BY CONCAT(url_alias.alias, '/', LOWER(brand_alias.field_brand_path_value))
```

Comment: Post the query you have, to start with something, maybe it only needs a small correction or alike, if not, then we will have a better understanding of your problem

Comment: There is stupid "select ... left join ... left join ... left join ..." that results first table. The main puprpose to get second table from first ;)

Comment: Why are you excluding `drives -> e+h` from the final result?, and do you actually want the `*` next to 'product` in the `material` column?

Comment: I should get unique category urls, each product referenced to one brand and unlimited counts of categories. Title of product haven't any matters at all.

Comment: You should really try to avoid using complex conditions in joins, especially use of functions on columns: `ON CONCAT('taxonomy/term/', th0.tid) = url_alias.source`

Comment: Okey, i've know it, but there is no another way to join this tables. You are trying to find weakness of query, but it's doesn't matters.

I need just one answer: how to select distinct values from second column grouping them in first. update post, maybe it will be more clear

Comment: Instead of the `GROUP BY` you could do a `SELECT DISTINCT`, but the performance should be about the same. I guess the performance bottleneck is somewhere else. The output from `EXPLAIN` might help you to figure out where the engine spends its time.

Comment: You don't need to use CONCAT in the GROUP BY. Just change your query to: GROUP BY url_alias.alias, brand_alias.field_brand_path_value. And use CONCAT only in the SELECT as a column. It works if you use in CONCAT only GROUP fields.

Comment: There is no luck

`/*[0:27:50][10156 ms]*/ GROUP BY CONCAT(url_alias.alias, '/', LOWER(brand_alias.field_brand_path_value))  
/*[0:28:31][10172 ms]*/ GROUP BY url_alias.alias, brand_alias.field_brand_path_value`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT   a.category, 
         CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.material, ' ', 1), ' *') AS material,
         brand,
         CONCAT(a.category, '/', a.brand) AS concattedval
FROM     (
             [Your Sub-Select Query]
         ) a
GROUP BY a.category, 
         material, 
         a.brand
```

Comment: Hm, your solution i've try first of all. It executes ~10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

> select  substring(new1,0,charindex('/',new1)) as category, 'product *'
>   as Material, substring(new1,charindex('/',new1)+1,len(new1)) as brand,
>   new1 from  (select distinct Category+'/'+brand as new1 from table)
>   temp